# What does いい です mean in お飲み物は何がいいですか?

Tags: words, hiragana

**Phrase:**

> お [飲]{の}み[物]{もの}　は　[何]{なに}　が　いい　です　か
>
> O nomimono wa nani ga ii desu ka?
>
> *What would you like to drink?*

What I would like to know is what いい です (ii des) does for the sentence here? I've read that いい can translate to "good", but I don't see how that fits here.

I'm *very* new to Japanese and my immediate reaction is to think this might translate to "What beverage is good?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your reaction is not that wrong actually. You just need to think about the context in which the sentence is being asked.

いい means indeed *good* and here the topic of the sentence are the drinks, marked by the particle は. So, a very literal translation could be: "talking about drinks, what is good?".

This construction with なにがいいですか is often used to ask someone what he would like to drink/eat etc. You can see it in English as if you added "for you" at the end of the question. Something like "What drink is good *for you*?". In a much broader sense, "What can I get you?".

In English of course you would hardly say "What drinks would be good?", hence the translation becomes more naturally "What would you like to drink?".

Answer (score 3):

You are correct with "What beverages are good?" in terms of word-for-word translation. However, いい (ii) and いいですか (ii desu ka) have different meanings.

> いい (ii) = good
>
> ～いいですか (ii desu ka) = Can I ~ , May I ~ (if you use the polity form),
>   would you like ~, are you okay with ~

If we directly translate "What do you like to drink?", it will become "なにをのみたいですか?". However, this isn't exactly polite.

* verb + tai = desire (e.g. のみたい=desire to drink, たべたい = desire to eat, みたい = desire to watch)

** Depending on the particle used in front, the meaning can change a little (ref: [Noun + で(も）いい　VS +がいい (=Noun + de(mo) ii vs + ga ii)](http://maggiesensei.com/2014/05/20/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%80%80vs%E3%80%80%E3%80%9C%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-de-ii-demo-ii-vs-ga-ii/))